# Pchart with mouseover

Tags: javascript, php, dom-events, pchart

I have pcharts on my website.
I want to add some JavaScript function for client side facility.
If any user mouseover on graph,it shows values on tooltip.
Is it possible?
Can anybody know how can I do this?
Please help me.

Comment: Duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/175115/how-to-show-ballon-tooltip-when-mouse-stops

Answer (score 2):

pChart supports this functionality out of the box. See here: http://pchart.sunyday.net/ImageMap/

Answer (score 0):

You can use the "**title**" attribute of HTML

```
<a id="tooltipsample" href="linktarget" title="Tooltip">Sample Link</a>
```

or set it in javascript

```
<script type="text/javascript">
document.getElementById(tooltipsample).title="New Tooltip";
</script>

<a id="tooltipsample" href="linktarget" title="Tooltip">Sample Link</a>
```

or with jquery

```
$('a#tooltipsample').attr('title', 'New Tooltip');
```